# how do I create a persistent Cache using UiWebView with objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, webview, persistent-storage

I have a `UIWebView` when using the `NSURLRequest` I’m setting `cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad` and also setting the pro cache memory size. When I open the application with internet, I open the screens and then deactivate the internet, the url I open is cached, until then everything is fine, but when closing the application and open again it loses all the cache. Can you persist the cache?
I have this:

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:500*1024*1024 diskCapacity:500*1024*1024 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

and loading from `UIWebView`:

```
NSURL *websiteURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];

NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:60.0];

[self.mainWebView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to load? What are the HTTP headers?

Comment: I am sending an authorization key and device id. But I ended up solving with cache.manifest. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve using a `cache.manifest` file on the server.